# Dynamics (FetchXML) - Error: Aggregates are not supported

Tags: powershell, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I'm fairly new to the FetchXML / Dynamics scene so please excuse my ignorance.

Up until now I've been executing a PowerShell Script that runs a FetchXML query to obtain user most recent login dates within Dynamics.

This has been working flawlessly for about a month, but as of about a week ago the script stopped accepting my FetchXML query throwing an error saying "Aggregates are not supported".

No changes to the code have been made what so ever.

Weirdly, the exact same code worked in the UAT Dynamics environment but not in production. After a couple more days it appears that it's stopped working in the UAT environment too.

Any ideas as to why this could be occurring? I'll post the code below.

Thanks All

```
$xml = [string]::Format('
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true" version="1.0">
            <entity name="audit">
                <attribute name="createdon" alias="lastlogin" aggregate="max" />
                <attribute name="auditid" alias="lastloginct" aggregate="count" />
                    <filter>
                        <condition attribute="operation" operator="eq" value="4" />
                        <condition attribute="createdon" operator="on-or-after" value="{0}" />
                    </filter>
                <link-entity name="systemuser" from="systemuserid" to="objectid" alias="su" link-type="inner">
                    <filter>
                        <condition attribute="domainname" operator="eq" value="{1}" />
                    </filter>
                    <attribute name="fullname" alias="fullname" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="firstname" alias="FirstName" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="lastname" alias="LastName" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="domainname" alias="domainname" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="accessmode" alias="accessmode" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="isdisabled" alias="isdisabled" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="businessunitid" alias="businessunitid" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="internalemailaddress" alias="internalemailaddress" groupby="true" />
                    <attribute name="systemuserid" alias="ObjectID" groupby="true"/>
                    <attribute name="ms_provider" alias="Provider" groupby="true"/>
                    <attribute name="mobilephone" alias="Mobile" groupby="true"/>
                </link-entity>
            </entity>
 </fetch>
 ', $date, $user.userprincipalname)
```

Comment: Well *something* must have changed... If it's not the fetchxml query itself, maybe a new MS CRM update was installed that changed this behaviour? And that update found its way to UAT either by installing the update there as well, or by importing a production database copy to UAT?

Comment: @LeonBouquiet thanks for your comment, something did indeed change.

I had a ticket raised with Microsoft, turns out they had rolled out a large update to their Audit tables in dynamics which removes the capability of aggregation and entity linking... bit of a shame when some of your solutions rely on this.